# Convert Date time in "Mon APR 6, 2012 11:12 am" format

Tags: android

I want to convert the date time in

```
Mon APR 6, 2012  11:12 am
```

this format

i am using

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM d, yyyy hh:mm a");
String date = formatter.format(d);
```

this code to get the date format but it returns

```
Mon Apr 6, 2012  11:12 am
```

i need Month in Caps and all other were same.

Is there any solution then please refer me.

Thanks

Comment: IMO, you need to write aditional code to achieve that. SimpleDateFormat does not provide such functionality.

Comment: i have't addition code that's why i am asking this question..

Comment: How you want.show me one example

Comment: @Pinki its already shown in the question.

Comment: i want date time in this "Mon APR 6, 2012  11:12 am" format.

But SimpleDateFormat returns "Mon Apr 6, 2012  11:12 am" format.

Comment: Thanks for all to share your knowledge with me ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at DateFormatSymbols
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html

Sample :

```
DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols();
symbols.setShortMonths(new String[]{"JAN","FEB"....});
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM d, yyyy hh:mm a", symbols);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get `Mon Apr 6, 2012  11:12 am` and month as chra using chatAt() function in to string array.then convert it use toUpperCase() method in string class to make them uppr

Answer (score 2):

Try this-

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

class Solution
{
        public static void main (String[] args)
        {
                Date d = new java.util.Date();
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM d, yyyy hh:mm a");
                String date = formatter.format(d);
                String month = date.substring(4, 7);
                date = date.replaceFirst(month, month.toUpperCase());
                System.out.println(date);

        }
}
```

But this doesn't work if your date format changes. You need to understand that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
Date d = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM d, yyyy hh:mm a");
        String date = formatter.format(d);
        Log.v("Test","Date==="+d);
        String[] temp;
        String month ;
        String final_string_date = "" ;
        temp = date.split(" ");
        for(int i =0; i < temp.length ; i++)
        {
            if(i==1)
                month=temp[i].toUpperCase();
            else
                month=temp[i];
            final_string_date = final_string_date+" "+  month;
        }
        Log.v("Test","final_string_date==="+final_string_date.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String DateFormat(String repdate,SimpleDateFormat formater )
{
    long d = Date.parse(repdate);       
    String[] arr= formater.format(d).split(" ");
    arr[1] = arr[1].toUpperCase();
    String date = "";
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        date = date + arr[i] +" ";
    }

    return date;
}
```

Pass your current date string and your date formater in ("EE MMM d, yyyy hh:mm a") format. you will get your solution.